# Fetch records from child relationship using Apex

Tags: apex, soql, relationships, dynamic-soql, childrelationship

I have a remote action that need to fetch an object child relationship data, but the catch is that is has to be dynamic.

For example, the remote action will get `Case`, `CaseComments`, list of fields in `CaseComments` and `CaseId` and it should fetch the first 5 records in `CaseComments` that are associated with the relevant case.

I'm using `Schema.ChildRelationship` to query the relation name, and then building the query.

For example, for the input `'Case', 'CaseComment', 'CommentBody, IsPublished', '123'` the query would look like:

`SELECT (SELECT CommentBody, IsPublished FROM CaseComments) FROM Case WHERE Id = '5000...'`

Now I'm using `Database.query` to fetch the results. I'm getting a `List` of `Case` objects, but only with the `Id` field. How can I access the child objects? When running this query using SoqlExplorer I get a column with the name of the relationship that contains the rows.

[image: soqlExplorer result]

This is the basic Apex code:

```
String query = 'SELECT (SELECT ' + fieldsList + ' FROM ' + relationName + ') FROM Case WHERE Id = \'' + (Id)caseId + '\'';
System.debug(objName + ' QUERY: ' + query);
SObject result = Database.query(query);
if (result == null) { return null; }
System.debug('RESULT: ' + JSON.serialize(result.get(relationName)));
```

When I run it I get an Exception: `System.SObjectException: Invalid field CaseComments for Case`.

How can I get the child object rows?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the debug output that includes ' QUERY: ' in your question as the problem is probably in the values of the variables you use to construct that query (as you have already established the correct syntax).

Comment: @KeithC The query is OK, when I copy-paste the query to SoqlExplorer I get the results. The query in the example was copied from the log.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna it does not work, I get an exception `System.SObjectException: Invalid aggregate relationship CaseComment for Case`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna got it to work, I passed to SObject name instead of the relation name to the `getSObjects` method. Thanks!